# ArrayFormula Added Condition, it returns 0 value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Value of my formula goes to 0 when applying ArrayFormula with added condition.

Initially I used:
`=ArrayFormula(max(if(Simplified!$B$4:$B$267=$K$2,Simplified!$E$4:$E$267)))`
to find the maximum value with one condition.

It works but when I added another condition which is
`=ArrayFormula(max(if(AND(Simplified!$B$4:$B$267=$K$2,Simplified!$K$4:$K$267=$K$3),Simplified!$E$4:$E$267)))`
it returns a value of 0

Here's the link of the gsheets:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AnbX80qgZjAArw4JUMo3rpIBtkm-BcACwb0FWpJzvE8/edit?usp=sharing

Help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Questions about google spreadsheets (˙ArrayFormula()˙ doesn't exist in Excel) are off-topic here, should be asked at webapps stackexchange.

Comment: @MátéJuhász is there a way to (quickly) determine if a function/feature is present/absent? I sometimes use one to answer questions about the other (G Sheets / Excel / Calc)

Comment: Check the attached goggle Sheet I've Written the same Formula as shown below in my Answer and its working, given same result 446.263.

Answer (score 1):

Write your formula like this:

`=ArrayFormula(MAX(IF(Simplified!$B$4:$B$267=$K$2,IF(Simplified!$K$4:$K$267=$K$3,Simplified!$E$4:$E$267))))`

Or, you can write the formula as shown below and enter it with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.  Google Sheets will automatically add the reserved word 'ArrayFormula' to the formula:

`=MAX(IF(Simplified!$B$4:$B$267=$K$2,IF(Simplified!$K$4:$K$267=$K$3,Simplified!$E$4:$E$267)))`